# Learning to implement dynamically typed language compiler

Tags: dynamic-typing, compiler

I'm interested in learning how to create a compiler for a dynamically typed language. Most compiler books, college courses and articles/tutorials I've come across are specifically for statically typed languages. I've thought of a few ways to do it, but I'd like to know how it's usually done. I know type inferencing is a pretty common strategy, but what about others?

Where can I find out more about how to create a dynamically typed language?

Edit 1:
  I meant dynamically typed. Sorry about the confusion.

I've written toy compilers for statically typed languages and written some interpreters for dynamically typed languages. Now, I'm interested in learning more about creating compilers for a dynamically typed language.  I'm specifically experimenting with LLVM and since I need to specify the type of every method and argument, I'm thinking of ways to implement a dynamically typed language on something like LLVM.

Comment: Dynamic compilers are almost exclusively only used in emulators as dynamic recompilers. This wouldn't happen to be your intention for researching the subject area, would it? And speaking of this, examining the source code to said emulators is probably your best bet for learning about dynamic compilers.

Comment: @Rob S, I'm thinking more along the lines of something like a scheme or common lisp compiler. I know most popular dynamic languages are interpreted, but I was thinking there have to be some compilers as well.

Comment: llvm is not different from any native target. You must have some form of runtime type information, you'd need an efficient implementation of a dynamic dispatch (e.g., for all the arithmetic operations over all of the types from Scheme numeric tower), and, if you're bold, you can use an abstract interpretation in order to specialise types wherever it is possible and explicitly get rid of a dynamic dispatch. That's it. The rest is pretty much the same as for the statically typed languages.

Answer (score 2):

[The Structure and Interpretation of Computer Programs](http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book.html) finishes with completing an entire interpreter for Scheme in Scheme.  Which can give you a good overview of how one could implement a dynamic language.

I would also recommend reading the Ruby source code.  I have not attempted to read it in many years.  But when I last tried, it was remarkably clear and easy to understand.  There are a lot of good ideas in there.

Answer (score 1):

For Scheme, read this: http://www.iro.umontreal.ca/~boucherd/mslug/meetings/20041020/minutes-en.html

IronPython sources could be useful too.

For the most advanced dynamic language compiler, see V8: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/V8_%28JavaScript_engine%29

Comment: Sure that's more advanced than, say, every Common Lisp compiler?

Comment: @David, surprisingly, yes, it is more advanced. Simply because Javascript is a way much more dynamic than Common Lisp, and thus a compiler should be much more complicated. Common Lisp compilers are relatively trivial, and they're providing enough functionality for improving performance manually (e.g., type hints). Javascript is a completely different beast.

Answer (score 1):

There's also [Write Yourself A Scheme In 48 Hours](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Write_Yourself_a_Scheme_in_48_Hours), in my eyes a great tutorial to implement a dynamic language (Scheme) in a strict language (Haskell).

Comment: After seeing Norvigs blog, I never trust these sort of `Learn X in Y Hours/Days/Weeks` title anymore

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested in a common lisp compiler--how it's done and so forth--you might check out the source code for [Armed Bear Common Lisp](http://common-lisp.net/project/armedbear/) and target some specific questions to that community. [Mac Ruby](http://www.macruby.org/) is a compiler for Ruby that uses the [LLVM](http://llvm.org/) infrastructure. The source code and community around either project could be valuable resources for you.

Comment: Both of those projects look awesome. I am actually trying to write toy compilers using LLVM, so the Mac Ruby implementation might be just what I need.

Answer (score 0):

> Where can I find out more about how to create a dynamically typed language?

["dynamically typed" is scary. "dynamic" is pretty common.]

Step 1.  Pick a dynamic language.  Really.  Choose one.

Step 2.  Google the language.  Really.  Use Google.

Step 3.  Find the source for the language.  It's easy.  Python, Ruby, Lua, Haskell, etc., the compilers and run-times are all online.  http://svn.python.org/view/, http://svn.ruby-lang.org/cgi-bin/viewvc.cgi/, http://www.lua.org/source/5.1/, http://hackage.haskell.org/package/haskell-src-1.0.1.4, http://code.google.com/p/fina-forth/source/browse/

Step 4.  Read.  Really.  Read the source for the compiler.  It's easy.  It's online.  The authors offer extensive documentation on their language.

What part of this is giving you problems?  Please be **specific** and **update** your question.

Comment: Haskell?!? *Dynamic*?!?

Comment: @SK-logic: I couldn't parse the question.  "Dynamic Type", "Dynamic".  I gave up and threw in a ringer for fun.

Comment: I bet that OP meant http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?DynamicTyping

Comment: @SK-logic: Quite possibly true.  The term still scares me because it leads to much confusion.  Example: folks asking for the Python equivalent to a cast operator.

Comment: @S.Lott, it actually makes sense. A dynamically typed language still can be annotated (by such 'casts'), which helps to fall back to a type inference in a smart static compiler. Many Common Lisp implementations are doing this.

Comment: I actually read "dramatically typed"; carried an entirely different meaning, that. ^^

Comment: @SK-logic: Python, however, doesn't have any sensible "dynamic" type capability.  Variables don't have defined types, but the type of an object is essentially unchangeable.  That makes a lot of sense.  Therefore, "dynamic type" scares me.

Comment: @S.Lott, what do you mean by "*the type of an object is essentially unchangeable*"? Python is using the duck typing - i.e., a function should be able to accept an argument of *any* type that provide expected methods and fields. If you annotate your code with specific types, compiler may optimise out a dynamic dispatch. Otherwise you have to use an abstract interpretation in order to specialise types wherever it is possible.

Comment: @SK-logic: Not talking about duck typing or how variables lack static type affinity.  An object itself (an actual instance) has a fixed relationship with a class.  There's no "cast" operation to magically re-interpret a bunch of bytes in memory as a different type of object.  This is different from the duck-typing concept that a variable (like a function parameter) could be any type of object with the proper interface.  In C++ or Java the object itself can be cast to a new class.  Not so in Python.

Comment: @S.Lott, a pointer cast in C or C++ is not re-interpreting anything, it also just hints a compiler that the object is *known*  to be of a certain type. And it would be a good idea to add such a cast to Python, it will allow to hint compilers to get rid of dynamic dispatch.

Comment: @SK-logic: "is not re-interpreting anything".  Um, you can have two classes which are pretty wildly different and cast between them.  It appears pretty arbitrary to my eye because there are so few rules for what constitutes a legal cast.   Indeed, it's way too easy to create C++ programs that use bad casts and crash.

Comment: @S.Lott, that kind of casts are only valid if you're casting from a subclass to a superclass (or from a superclass to a subclass if you really *know* that it is there). Both ways, this casting allows a compiler to dispatch method calls statically (and even to eliminate virtual calls). And in a language with duck typing (or with a prototype-based OOP, such as in Javascript) it should be possible to do the very same thing. You either hint a compiler or a compiler should be very smart to hint itself.

Comment: @SK-logic: I'm unclear on what "hinting to the compiler" even means in a dynamic language.  Since the compiler for Python doesn't actually do very much.  The idea of "static dispatching" in Python doesn't seem sensible.  My point is simply that the words "dynamic type" seem oxymoronic to me in the context of Python.  It's absolutely the case that type really is dynamic in a language with a cast operator (like C++).  But a "dynamic" language (i.e., undeclared variables) seems different from a "dynamic type" (i.e. casting).

Comment: @S.Lott, by giving compiler a hint that the value is guaranteed to be of a certain type (or at least that you're sure it is), you can lower the language from dynamic to static. So, instead of calling a dynamic method you can statically call a known function with a known address. And I do not know what the "*dynamic type*" is, we're talking about a dynamic type systems, not types. See what V8 is doing, for example, in a context of a completely dynamic type system it is capable of infering statically known types and eliminate dynamic dispatch.